# TPM configuration fails on a Thinkpad T510 due to missing kernel modules

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, tpm

[Running 14.04 LTS.]

I'm trying to setup the TPM chip on my T510. I've been following the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/414755/507853 but I'm having the following issue:

```
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# ls -la
total 148
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 23 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root  4096 Feb 23 20:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Feb 23 20:08 st33zp24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11449 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_atmel.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12097 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_crb.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11857 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_i2c_atmel.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15361 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_i2c_infineon.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21321 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_i2c_nuvoton.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25273 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_infineon.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16145 Feb 20 04:23 tpm_nsc.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14489 Feb 20 04:23 xen-tpmfront.ko

root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_atmel.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_atmel.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_crb.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_crb.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_i2c_atmel.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_i2c_atmel.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_i2c_infineon.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_i2c_infineon.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_i2c_nuvoton.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_i2c_nuvoton.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_infineon.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_infineon.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe tpm_nsc.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module tpm_nsc.ko not found.
root@FEYNMAN:/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm# modprobe xen-tpmfront.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module xen-tpmfront.ko not found.
```

I've tried rebooting but it makes no difference. The TPM is already enabled/active from my previous Windows 10 install (I also double-checked in BIOS just to be sure.)

Is someone able to help?

Comment: What does `uname -a` say, when run straight after your failed modprobe calls?

Comment: uname -a
    Linux MAXWELL 4.2.0-30-generic #35~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:48:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `depmod -a` and then repeat your `modprobe` commands.

According to the `man modprobe`:

> `modprobe` expects an up-to-date `modules.dep` file, as generated by `depmod`. This file lists what other modules each module needs (if any), and `modprobe` uses this to add or remove these dependencies automatically.

As soon as this file was updated, use `modprobe` command without paths and `.ko` extension:

```
modprobe module_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same result, each fail with the module 'not found'.

Comment: I suppose you called `depmod` from the superuser shell and while being in `/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/`? Are your modules listed in `/lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/modules.dep` after its invocation? If not, try running `depmod` with `-v` key (verbose mode). BTW, there's to need to add `.ko` to the name of your modules: `modprobe tpm_atmel`. Maybe that's the cause of your errors? Have you tried `insmod /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/char/tpm/tpm_atmel.ko` command to install module instead?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the modprobe commands are working today. I haven't changed anything.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe the moon phase has changed...