# Ubuntu 16.04 does not reboot after manual error fix

Tags: error-handling

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I am facing the following problem:  I tried to open my PC and got an error concerning the filesystem that suggested to do fsck manually.
I did:

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

And fixed all the errors by saying yes.
I then tried to reboot, but my system freezes as it is shown below:

```
A TMP error (6) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
Systemd[1] : failed to isolate default target: Unit multiuser.target not found.freezing execution.
```

What should I do? Is it a kind of systematic Ubuntu error or can it be my motherboard for example?

I really need your help cause I am new to Linux and the PC belongs to my research team not to me... so terrified of losing data!

Comment: First thing to do is to backup all the data. If Ubuntu doesn't work, try a live USB image to boot with. After that, look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/778875/tpm-error-6-when-booting-thinkpad

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I followed the link but the error resists...any further suggestion?

Comment: Any further advice please?? The problem still remains...

Comment: I'm not familiar with this problem. I googled it and I found several posts about it. When you try those, write down what you try and what are the results so you can ask a detailed question if you need further assistance.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462415/ .