# Ubuntu replacement

Tags: system

How can I replace one Linux OS with another? I am facing issues to install Ubuntu via USB drive. I get an error that says "failed to claim resource file1" and "platform device creation failed". Please help to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please add into the question more details: the error message is lacking specific information. There should be somehing like "MSFT0101" at the front of "platform device creation failed".

Comment: Yes exactly the same code. Everyone is saying switch to Windows, but I am still hopeful for ubuntu. Just help me to reestablish my faith in linux.

Answer (score 6):

> how to uninstall an older os

You don't.

> How can I replace one linux os with another?

The same way you installed it the 1st time: you format the partition during installation of the new operating system

> Computer says, "failed to claim resource file1" and "platform device creation failed".

That is an error related to a Microsoft license for their "trusted platform" scheme. Please add the platform it refers to in the eror message. If it is MSFT0101 then it is an ACPI device ID referring to the Intel Management Engine Interface (and that is part of TPM). [Disable in your BIOS if possible](http://blog.ptsecurity.com/2017/08/disabling-intel-me.html) but we also have TPM drivers that might fix this but you need to be on Ubuntu for that: See [Does Ubuntu use TPM 2.0 chip?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414747/does-ubuntu-use-tpm-2-0-chip) Other Linux will have different solutions for this.